# Engines in Python Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

In the document for `pd.read_csv()` method in pandas in python while describing the "sep" parameter there is a mention of engines such as C engine and Python engine.

The document link is :
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

What are these engines? What is the role of each engine? Is there any analogy which can help understand these engines better?

Answer (score 17):

The [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation notes specific differences between 'c' (default) and 'python' engines. The names indicate the language in which the parsers are written. Specifically, the docs note:

> Where possible pandas uses the C parser (specified as `engine='c'`), but
>   may fall back to Python if C-unsupported options are specified.

Here are the main differences you should note (as of v0.23.4):

- **'c' is faster**, while 'python' is currently more feature-complete.
- **'python' supports `skipfooter`**, while 'c' does not.
- **'python' supports flexible `sep`** other than a single character (inc regex), while 'c' does not.
- **'python' supports `sep=None` with `delim_whitespace=False`**, which means it can auto-detect a delimiter, while 'c' does not.
- **'c' supports `float_precision`**, while 'python' does not (or not necessary).

Version notes:

- **`dtype`** supported in 'python' v0.20.0+.
- **`delim_whitespace`** supported in 'python' v0.18.1+.

Note the above *may* change as features are developed. You should check [IO Tools (Text, CSV, HDF5, …)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-the-parser-engine) if you see unexpected behaviour in later versions.

Comment: For a 1.2 GB csv file, `engine='python'` is much faster than `c`. Why is that?

Comment: @serafeim, Without your CSV file, it's difficult to tell. Perhaps there is specific content or combination or arguments where `engine='python'` is more efficient. Generally, though, `'c'` is more efficient while `'python'` is more feature-complete.

Comment: Here is the file: https://filebin.net/fkyil2m5yhvr1dbh any tip would be great. `c` takes forever whereas `python` is faster

Answer (score 0):

My `timeit` on the `pandas` `engine` option. Yes! `c` is much faster than `python` but, even surprisingly, not using the engine is much faster.

Here are the results while importing the same data:

```
%timeit df = pd.read_csv(data_loc,engine='c')
4.38 s ± 423 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df = pd.read_csv(data_loc,engine='python')
17.2 s ± 1 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df = pd.read_csv(data_loc) 
4.02 s ± 58.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

print(df.shape)
(1116077, 24)
```

Comment: You are always using an engine, the default is "c", hence the similar times.