# How to create a data frame from a text file

Tags: dataframe

I am having trouble creating a data frame with the following data:

```
Force (N)   microstrain1    microstrain2    microstrain3    microstrain4    microstrain5
24.838      9.689       -20.299     19.785      15.601      -7.681
49.691      22.610      -40.797     41.304      32.200      -15.332
75.309      33.357      -61.678     62.512      48.726      -22.422
97.227      41.944      -80.524     81.011      62.266      -30.228
121.641     52.692      -100.775    100.703     77.248      -36.884
```

Every time I try to use a delimiter I get the following message:

```
/Users/macbookpro/PycharmProjects/Projects/Lab_3/Bending.py:5: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  df1 = pd.read_csv('MEE322-thurs_1040_group1_9.5cm.txt',delimiter='  ')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking about debugging a problem we need the smallest code that demonstrates the problem in the question itself. Without that we're left guessing what you wrote, which hardly helps when giving advice or answers. See "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the python engine instead of the c engine?:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('MEE322-thurs_1040_group1_9.5cm.txt', delimiter=' ', engine='python')
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I changed from windows to mac and never had this problem, is there a reason why ?

Comment: This might answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774459/engines-in-python-pandas-read-csv I think it comes down to the c option is faster but the python option supports more stuff.